# Error - 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'seconds'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making an app where a textfield input is shown on a label for the amount of time (in seconds) indicated on an other textfield. My app only runs when `var seconds` is set to an integer and not to the textfield input. When I set `var seconds` to the textfield input, I get the following error on the indicated lines of code: `'ViewController' does not have a member named 'seconds'` Can anyone help? Thanks.

Here is all of my code, the lines of code with the error have `//Error` beside them:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var chronometre: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var prochainpointLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pointactuelLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var point1Textfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var point1tempsTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var point2Textfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var point2tempsTextfield: UITextField!

var timer = NSTimer()
var seconds = point1tempsTextfield.text.toInt()

func subtractTime(dt:NSTimer){
        seconds-- //Error
        chronometre.text = "\(seconds)" //Error
    if(seconds == 0) { //Error
        seconds = point2tempsTextfield.text.toInt()
        pointactuelLabel.text = point2Textfield.text
        prochainpointLabel.text = nil

    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





@IBAction func presenterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    pointactuelLabel.text = point1Textfield.text
    prochainpointLabel.text = point2Textfield.text
    chronometre.text = "\(seconds)" //Error
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: ("subtractTime:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

}
```

Thank you for your help, I am very new to coding and really appreciate it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28666059/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Forget about using a timer to calculate time. You should use NSTimeInterval between two dates to measure elapsed time.

[ElapsedTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666059/2303865)

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%02d:%02d", Int((self/60.0)%60), Int((self) % 60 ))
    }
}


var startTime:NSTimeInterval = 0
var elapsedTime:NSTimeInterval = 0

startTime =  NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate  // 446644854.4675

sleep(3)   //
elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime  // 3.005680024623871

println(elapsedTime.time) "00:03"
```

// applying this concept to your code would look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var chronometre: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prochainpointLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointactuelLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var point1Textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var point1tempsTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var point2Textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var point2tempsTextfield: UITextField!

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var startTime:NSTimeInterval = 0

    func updateTime(){
        chronometre.text = (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime).time
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func presenterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        pointactuelLabel.text = point1Textfield.text
        prochainpointLabel.text = point2Textfield.text
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1/10, target: self, selector: ("updateTime:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime =  NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate  

    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to use NSTimeInterval and I cannot find any tutorials. Do you know if there's a website or a video that can tell me? @Leonardo Savio Dabus

Comment: As I said earlier, I am new to coding. I do not really understand the code in the link. But is there any way that I can do this with my current NSTimer? @Leonardo Savio Dabus

Comment: I have updated the answer with every single step you need to get the elapsed time between two dates (which represents a point in time)

Comment: As you can see I asked the computer to sleep for 3 seconds and it will always take a little bit longer to complete the task. Thats why you can't use a timer to chronometer time. It may be a small difference but it will increase with time. If you need further explanation just let me know.

Comment: Ok, there's only one error on the following line `chronometre.text = (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime).time` the error is `'NSTimeInterval' is not convertible to 'UInt8'` @Leonardo

Comment: there must be something else wrong NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate returns NSTimeInterval (same as Double)

Comment: How do I send you the project? @Leonardo

Comment: Do you have Dropbox ?

Comment: right click your project enclosing folder and select compress\

Comment: this will create a zip file. just post it to www.dropbox.com and share the link

Comment: Are you able to fix it? @Leonardo

Comment: I could but I wouldn't help you doing it for you I rather try to explain what part of my code you don't understand. This way you wouldn't need help to solve any issue you might encounter ahead.

Comment: I only copy/pasted the code above into my project. Perhaps there was something else I was supposed put in my code? @Leonardo